# Replace entry in JSON field PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How can I replace the `"foo"` entry in this JSON *(not JSONB)* field with `"three"`

```
SELECT name, settings FROM users;
```

```
name  | settings
----------------------------
"bob" | {"foo": "one", "bar": "two"}
```

I want this in my DB

```
name  | settings
----------------------------
"bob" | {"foo": "three", "bar": "two"}
```

Comment: Before this is closed, how on God's green Earth does this question need more focus?

Comment: Have you tried [Replace](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-replace/)?

Comment: @eglease I have, but was getting type errors `function replace(json, unknown, unknown) does not exist` or `function replace(json, unknown, jsonb) does not exist`

Comment: ah @eglease, you genius. `replace(settings::text, 'one', 'three')::json` works. If you want internet points you can make an answer, else I'll do that

Comment: What happens when you do this `SELECT name, Replace(setting, 'one ', 'three') AS S FROM users;` ?

Comment: btw I used `UPDATE users SET settings = replace ...`

Comment: But what if you want to only replace foo's value of one but not bar's value of one?

Comment: @Isolated yeah good point. That would be good to know. I guess you replace `"foo": "one"` with `"foo": "three"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several [json-functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and one of them is jsonb_set():

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
    '{"foo": "one", "bar": "two"}'::jsonb -- current json
  , '{foo}' -- path
  , '"three"' -- new value
);
```

Output: {"bar": "two", "foo": "three"}

By the way, it's a jsonb function that takes jsonb as input and returns jsonb as well. You can always cast between json and jsonb if needed.

Comment: thanks. I realise I worded my question vaguely. I want to update the field in the DB. I take it casting to jsonb and back again will work with updates?

Comment: Yes it does, no problem. Just give it a try and you will see.